# Scale and dragging image inside canvas only in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have been struggling for the past week in transformation of image within the limits of canvas

```
void  image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
var name = (Image)sender;    
var translate = (CompositeTransform)name.RenderTransform;
var newPosX = Canvas.GetLeft(name) + translate.TranslateX + e.Delta.Translation.X;
var newPosY = Canvas.GetTop(name) + translate.TranslateY + e.Delta.Translation.Y;
if (!isBoundary(newPosX, DrawCanvas.ActualWidth - name.ActualWidth, 0))
translate.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
if (!isBoundary(newPosY, DrawCanvas.ActualHeight - name.ActualHeight, 0))
translate.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
bool isBoundary(double value, double max, double min)
        {
            return value > max ? true : value < min ? true : false;
        }
```

This is my dragging code it works fine and also isBoundary function limits the image inside canvas inly but when I am scaling with this code

```
{
     var translate = (CompositeTransform)name.RenderTransform;
     translate.CenterX = name.ActualWidth / 2;
     translate.CenterY = name.ActualHeight / 2;
     translate.ScaleX += e.Delta.Translation.X*0.001 ;
     translate.ScaleY += e.Delta.Translation.Y*0.001;
```

}

Scale is also done but not limiting inside canvas and I when I scale my image to make big its canvas is also scaling and when I am shriking in size its canvas (drag) area is also shrinking.
Need help in limiting scaling and its canvas problem.

Comment: Try setting CenterX/Y to .5/.5. I think these might be based on 0..1 range.

Comment: Same behaviour I want to restrict scaling within canvas only and provide a message that limit exceed etc?

Comment: I think my code is not general for all type of transformation within canvas only.

Comment: What needs to be added in my code?

Comment: `translate.CenterX = .5;`

Comment: Scaling is alright but boundary problems still remains ?

Comment: When I drag my mouse it scale through all the page and so on , means unlimited scaling.

Comment: How would you like to limit scaling? Not allow any pixel of the photo to be outside of the view port?

Comment: some thing like IsBoundary function to check scaling is inside or not if not then pop up message

Comment: Please run that code if you got time you will understand my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to limit transformation of images inside canvas in window store app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23996120/how-to-limit-transformation-of-images-inside-canvas-in-window-store-app)