# How to limit transformation of images inside canvas in window store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, transform

I have been struggling for two weeks for this problem . I am applying dragging and scaling to an image inside canvas.Dragging works fine and is limiting inside canvas IsBoundary functions but when I am applying scaling its drag area changes . If increases scaling with mouse drag area increases also and whem I make it shrink in size drag area also shrinks.Help me to solve this problem of limiting scaling
Thanks.
Here is my code link
[sample](http://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=FF57BAE90AC42267!1745)

Comment: That would be expected behavior, you're saying you want the area that's giving the hittestvisibility to stay the same size regardless of its current scale?

Comment: yes canvas remains same but scaling only applies to image

Comment: So the Canvas is scaling and not the image? Sorry a bit confused.

Comment: First you drag the image it works fine. Then when you tap the image its opacity becomes 0.5 then drag the image it will scale then again tap to make opacity 1 . Then make it drag you will some difference in its area  .

Comment: I want that when the image is going out of canvas a popup message show and say that limit exceed cant' scale more .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question. When you scale an item in a canvas the translation needs to account for the change in scale. Is that right?

Assuming this XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Border Width="500"
            Height="500"
            BorderBrush="White"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
            <Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle"
                       Width="50"
                       Height="50"
                       Fill="CornflowerBlue">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="225" TranslateY="225" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Try this code-behind:

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    MyRectangle.ManipulationMode =
        ManipulationModes.TranslateX
        | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
    var transform = MyRectangle.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    var reposition = new Action<double, double>((x, y) =>
    {
        var size = new Size(MyRectangle.ActualWidth * transform.ScaleX, MyRectangle.ActualHeight * transform.ScaleY);
        var location = MyRectangle.TransformToVisual(MyRectangle).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));

        var minX = -location.X;
        var maxX = MyCanvas.ActualWidth - size.Width;
        var newX = Within(x, minX, maxX);
        transform.TranslateX = Within(newX, minX, maxX);

        var minY = -location.Y;
        var maxY = MyCanvas.ActualHeight - size.Height;
        var newY = Within(y, minY, maxX);
        transform.TranslateY = Within(newY, minY, maxY);
    });
    MyRectangle.ManipulationDelta += (s, e) =>
    {
        var newX = transform.TranslateX + e.Delta.Translation.X;
        var newY = transform.TranslateY + e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        reposition(newX, newY);
    };
    MyRectangle.PointerWheelChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        // require control
        if (Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control)
            == Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.None)
            return;

        // ignore horizontal
        var props = e.GetCurrentPoint(MyRectangle).Properties;
        if (props.IsHorizontalMouseWheel)
            return;

        // apply scale
        var newScale = transform.ScaleX + (double)props.MouseWheelDelta * .001;
        transform.ScaleX = transform.ScaleY = newScale;

        // reposition
        reposition(transform.TranslateX, transform.TranslateY);
    };
}

public double Within(double value, double min, double max)
{
    if (value <= min)
        return min;
    else if (value >= max)
        return max;
    else
        return value;
}
```

I hope this helps.

> Note: Since I am not on a touch machine right now, I implemented the mouse wheel to scale. But you can modify the code as you want. The logic would be identical.

Best of luck!

Comment: Awesome work bro you saved me (y)                                           Please explain a little?

Comment: Sure. Reposition() is the key method. It ensures that the translation is not outside the bounds of the `Canvas`. Just make sure you call it to translate and after you scale.

Comment: if (MyRectangle.Opacity == 0.5)
                {
                    var translate = (CompositeTransform)MyRectangle.RenderTransform;
                    translate.ScaleX += e.Delta.Translation.X * 0.005;
                    //translate.ScaleY += e.Delta.Translation.Y * 0.005;

                    // reposition
                    reposition(transform.TranslateX, transform.TranslateY);
                    
                }

Comment: but it still going out when I scale more ?

Comment: Why don't you update my code with your code so I can see it complete. Or you can email me a working sample project jnixon@microsoft(.com)